# Variwide charts in Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to create a chart like this in Highcharter to use in R.

Ideally, what I would like to do is a bar chart where the width of the bar is the spread over the amount of days for which the event has happened. 
I have tried using "pointWidth", however, I need the bar width to be variable depending on the length of the event.

Here is the dataframe I am trying to plot:

`df <- data.frame(event = c("wedding", "party", "concert"),
                 start_date = as.Date(c("2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-11-20")),
                 end_date = as.Date(c("2017-10-10", "2017-11-18","2017-12-01")),
                 event_days = c(9,17,11),
                 customers = c("400", "150", "3000"))`

Here is how I would normally do it in ggplot:

`ggplot(df, aes(start_date, customers, width = event_days)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

What I am trying to do is technically getting the width of the bars to be over the days over which the event took place.

[This is what I would like to achieve - x-axis to be a timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC6zf.png)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'variwide'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Labor Costs in Europe, 2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/' +
            'labour-market/labour-costs/main-tables">eurostat</a>'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
            text: 'Column widths are proportional to GDP'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Labor Costs',
        data: [
            ['Norway', 50.2, 335504],
            ['Denmark', 42, 277339],
            ['Belgium', 39.2, 421611],
            ['Sweden', 38, 462057],
            ['France', 35.6, 2228857],
            ['Netherlands', 34.3, 702641],
            ['Finland', 33.2, 215615],
            ['Germany', 33.0, 3144050],
            ['Austria', 32.7, 349344],
            ['Ireland', 30.4, 275567],
            ['Italy', 27.8, 1672438],
            ['United Kingdom', 26.7, 2366911],
            ['Spain', 21.3, 1113851],
            ['Greece', 14.2, 175887],
            ['Portugal', 13.7, 184933],
            ['Czech Republic', 10.2, 176564],
            ['Poland', 8.6, 424269],
            ['Romania', 5.5, 169578]

        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '€{point.y:.0f}'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Labor Costs: <b>€ {point.y}/h</b><br>' +
                'GDP: <b>€ {point.z} million</b><br>'
        },
        colorByPoint: true
    }]

});
```

```css
#container {
 max-width: 800px;
 min-width: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variwide.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see how your example is related to your question? There are no dates in your example. Have you tried using the variwide chart with the number of milliseconds as some kind of width?

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Have you reed this https://dantonnoriega.github.io/ultinomics.org/post/2017-04-05-highcharter-explainer.html? css don't seem the right tag here

Comment: Sorry folks this is my first post ever here. I have updated the question.

Comment: Is this what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/j70kpzc8/4/?

Comment: What I would need is the x-axis to be a timeline rather than the categories. 
Please check the link I have provided in the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointRange` property (that belongs to a series) is responsible for giving the columns a proper span.

Two simple solutions came to my mind:

**1.** Create a separate series for every point, apply `pointRange` and disable `grouping`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x8c3Ldwc/

**2.** Ignore `pointRange` and use area series instead (separate series for every column). Some special configuration (`plotOptions` in the demo) has to be applied to make it look like a column chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o1o5Ly1y/

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to translate what Kamil has provided on jsfiddle to Highcharter in the following way.

Firstly, the data has to be in a different format as opposed to the way I have described in the question.

```
   df2 <- data.frame(start_date = as.Date(c("2017-10-01", "2017-10-10", "2017-11-01", "2017-11-02", "2017-12-01", "2017-12-15")),
              customers = c(400,400, 200, 200,150,150),
              event = c("wedding","wedding", "party", "party", "concert","concert"))
```

Secondly, the chart type has to be set to "area" instead of column:

```
highchart() %>% 
    hc_add_series(df2, "area", hcaes(x = datetime_to_timestamp(start_date), 
    y = customers, group = event)) %>% 
hc_xAxis(type = "datetime",
       title = "",
       showFirstLabel = FALSE,
       showLastLabel = FALSE,
       enableMouseTracking = TRUE) %>% 
hc_plotOptions(area = list(marker = list(
       enabled = FALSE,
       lineWidth = 0,
       states = list(
       hover = list(enabled = FALSE))))) %>% 
hc_tooltip(followPointer = TRUE)
```