# The type 'variwide' in highcharter does not work

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to create a variwide chart in Highcharter to use in R,but the result is empty。

```
library(data.table)
library(highcharter)

labor_cost <- data.table(country =c('挪威','丹麦','比利时','瑞典','法国','荷兰','芬兰','德国','奥地利','爱尔兰','意大利','英国','西班牙','希腊','葡萄牙','捷克共和国','波兰','罗马尼亚'),cost=c(50.2,42,39.2,38,35.6,34.3,33.2,33,32.7,30.4,27.8,26.7,21.3,14.2,13.7,10.2,8.6,5.5),gdp=c(335504,277339,421611,462057,2228857,702641,215615,3144050,349344,275567,1672438,2366911,1113851,175887,184933,176564,424269,169578))

highchart() %>%
hc_title(text = "欧洲各国人工成本", align="center")%>%
hc_xAxis(type = "category",title = list(text = "* 柱子宽度与 GDP 成正比")) %>%
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
hc_add_series(data = labor_cost,type = "variwide",hcaes(x = country,width= gdp),dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,format="€{point.y:.0f}"),colorByPoint = TRUE)
```

The code executes normally，no errors appear.

Comment: Do R provide a console like in a web browser where you see errors ? If it does please share the error with us.

Comment: The code can execute normally，no error appear.

Comment: I'm guessing this needs something like `hc_add_dependency(name='variwide.js')`, where variwide.js is the variwide module. But I'm not sure.

Comment: As I see in the `highcharter` wrapper documentation, there is no 'variwide' series type defined in this wrapper. I found the reported issue on its repository, with the similar question. Here is the link: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/428

Comment: See the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386265/variwide-charts-in-highcharter
I had the same questions and managed to solve it in the end.